# Input offset voltage, input bias current, input offset current of operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, input-offset-voltage

Are operational amplifier parameters such as input offset voltage, input bias current, input offset current DC noise? Can I get rid of these noises by using a high-pass filter? If not, how can I get rid of these noises?

Answer (score 1):

They are all DC errors that may contribute to a significant DC error on the output signal. I say "may" because this depends on the actual circuit implementation and (some) component values.

> Can I get rid of these noises by using a high-pass filter?

Some of these DC errors can drift with time so, using a high pass filter with the wrong values may not effectively remove those errors.

> If not, how can I get rid of these noises?

It's important for any design that seeks to reduce errors to use the most appropriate component values and, if that is still insufficient, then use better op-amps.

One parameter that you have not mentioned is the change in CMRR with common-mode input level changes. This can create a substantial DC error if not taken care of. It can also produce a significant in-band AC error term if the input common mode signal level is changing. This latter error may not easily be got rid of by high pass filtering.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get rid of these noises by using a high-pass filter?

Can you **reduce** noise by using a filter? Yes.

Can you "get rid of" (completely remove) the noise? No.

There will always be some noise left.

The important question to answer is: **How much noise can you tolerate.**

Also: if the circuit generates more noise than what you can tolerate, how can that be solved.

You're probably a beginner and think that all non-ideal properties of any opamp are problematic. Fact is that usually they're not. There are "need to know" things that apply to the circuit around the opamp. Get these things right and the opamp will sometimes be the limiting factor. Get these things wrong and no matter what opamp you use, things will not improve.

For example: for low noise circuits you need to use low value resistors. High value resistors generate more thermal noise. So using an ultra-low-noise opamp is pointless when the feedback network around the opamp uses resistors with values in the order of Mega ohms.